# Experience Manager lock symbol in Tridion

Tags: experience-manager, lock-type

We are facing an issue with Experience Manager (XPM) in Tridion 2011 SP1.

After clicking the `Edit` button, the lock symbol for a particular Component appears on another different Component which is on top of the Page and is causing problems for site editors.

All other functionality is working fine w.r.t. XPM. Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe the component is checked out/locked? Can you explain a bit more about the "another different component on top of the page"? Is it a wrapper component? Is the page itself?

Comment: As Nuno highlighted, it would help if you could add more information to this ticket.

Can you also check if the component is inherited from a higher level in the blueprint? In this scenario, you will either have to localize the component for inline editing or edit the parent component using forms view.

Comment: The comp is not locked. Our website structure is - we have a top hero banner, then just below we have three small banner placed side by side. Now out of the below three banners the first two banners are in same div and have their lock on top of them. But lock symbol for the third comp is appearing on the top hero banner which is creating confusion.

Comment: Sounds like your HTML might be a bit messy or containing non closed tags, could you perhaps edit your question and add some of the source code of the Page? Adding a screenshot of the issue would also be helpful in explaining what exactly you see that is a problem.

Comment: We were able to fix the lock placement, but the border around the component is not completely wrapping around it. A small grey border shows on top left of the component instead of covering the full component region.

Comment: Please post and even self-accept if you know what fixed the lock issued and the small grey border issue. Bart's point on messy markup can also create the small borders--if you inspect the element in the browser you might find a span or other HTML node that's not nested or styled correctly.